# Gmail SMS notification

Tags: gmail

Does anyone know if there's a *free* way to do the following on Gmail:

Send a text message (SMS) to a specific mobile number whenever a new email arrives.  I'm not bothered if the SMS doesn't contain any part of the email, would just like a notification that an email has arrived so the laptop can be booted to check.

This is for my parents who have a very low-traffic account, usually go days without even looking at their laptop and don't have a smartphone, tablet or any other instant-on device (so checking is a bit of a chore).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your use case seems to be ideal for [If This Then That (IFTTT)](https://ifttt.com/).

> IFTTT is a service that lets you create powerful connections with one simple statement: if this then that.

So you could set up an IFTTT trigger which will send an SMS every time there's a new email. To make it easier for you, there's [existing recipe](https://ifttt.com/recipes/11930). The recipe will send you an SMS containing the message:

```
Gmail :: {{FromAddress}} :: {{Subject}}
```

Just [signup for IFTTT](https://ifttt.com/join), head over to [this recipe](https://ifttt.com/recipes/11930) and click on Use This Recipe.

Comment: That looks great, does it work with any UK mobile provider?

Comment: @SteB it should - I'm not in the UK so can't tell you for sure

Comment: Just tried that and it works a treat, thanks.

Comment: @SteB glad to hear, Cheers :)

Answer (score 0):

hey the best way to get the SMS alerts for new email in your Gmail account is to use [WeekWill.com](http://www.weekwill.com).

It works very fast and it sends out SMS text message to your mobile number whenever you get email in your inbox.

Comment: Looks like a very promising (& customizable) service, unfortunately I'm looking for a free service because of the low volume of email notifications.